# SSD Block Sizing

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, storage, logical-drive

I've been looking at logical and physical block sizes for disks...

- **[old disks]** logically(4KB) -> physically(8 * 512B) [-------Data Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster)
- **[new disks,old OS]** logically(4KB) -> physically(4KB(8 * 512B)) [------AF *512e Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512e)
- **[new disks,new OS]** logically(4KB) -> physically(4KB) [-------4K Native Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#4K_native)

---

But I'm new to SSDs, and been [reading](http://www.oo-software.com/en/docs/whitepaper/whitepaper_ssd.pdf) (see below) that SSDs don't have physical sectors they have physical pages... and those pages get "logically" associated to what is called a block on SSD.

> SSD layout In contrast to the hard disk, a SSD consists of
>   semiconductor memory building blocks, it contains no mechanical parts.
>   The smallest unit of an SSD is a page, which is composed of several
>   memory cells, and is usually 4 KB in size. Several pages on the SSD
>   are summarized to a block. A block is the smallest unit of access on a
>   SSD. Currently, 128 pages are mostly combined into one block;
>   therefore, a block contains 512 KB.

Questions:

- Are SSDs made in other page/block sizes other then this (4KB/512KB)?
- If the SSDs "block size" comes in 512KB

  - can I logically address(4KB) -> physical(4KB)?
  - or even, logically(512KB) -> physical(512KB(128 * 4KB))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, all IDE/SATA hard drives expose *either* 512B or 4KB sized blocks (depending on make and model) for read/write operations. Those are the only two options available (shame, because I can imagine other [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) sizes being very advantageous).

When an OS reads/writes to a hard drive, it has to manage the difference between the file system's sector size and the hard drive's [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) size. For a 512B hard drive, writing a 4K NTFS sector requires *8 x 512B* writes. You can see how a 4K drive might perform better given that the same operation would only take *1 x 4K* write.

The way SSDs do things internally varies by make and model. [Page sizes can be different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_memories).

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see those sizes on that wikipedia page...

Comment: what is (+128) for? `64 pages of 4,096+128 bytes each for a block size of 256 KiB`

Comment: @JordanDavis From the same wikipedia article *"associated with each page are a few bytes (typically 1/32 of the data size) that can be used for storage of an error correcting code (ECC)"*. That's what the +128 is for ;-)